# Browsing through Windows drives would run Wine

Tags: wine, pcmanfm

I've set Wine to open up as a window.

While in Lubuntu, there are cases when I'm browsing through my Windows files (I'm not running anything yet) then Wine pops up, then closes. No visible program is seen running.

This happens on certain folders only.

Should I be worried?

Comment: I would try to replace wine with a script that would log the arguments it just got. For example: write in a script first line as `#!/bin/sh`, and the second line as `echo "Arguments are: $@" >> /tmp/1 && ~/wine $@`. Then move the `/usr/bin/wine` script to the home directory, next move the script to `/usr/bin/wine` *(don't forget to give executable rights with `chmod +x `)*. After wine was called again, you should see the arguments in the `/tmp/1` file, so you will know what was called.

Comment: Sorry about that thing earlier. Anyway, this is the output for when I'm browsing through the folders: `Arguments are: winepath.exe -u `. **off-topic** _I tried running a regular windows executable, and it returns the path to that exe_.

Comment: Okay, you could also add a line `echo "my parent PID is $$" >> /tmp/1`, so you will know the parent PID, and you can find the parent process by running something like `ps -A | grep <the_pid_you_got>`.

Comment: I don't know what could cause it, I'm just keep guessing. I've no idea why would pcmanfm call `wine`, it seems a non-sense — perhaps the file manager calls another program that in turn calls wine? That's why I'm point to look at the parent PID. Also the «winepath.exe» is a pretty strange argument to me. Try running `grep -rnI "winepath.exe" ~/.config/` — perhaps you would find anything?

Comment: The PID keeps changing between each run/folder. Each time I try `ps -A | grep <the_pid_I_got>` I get no messages. Finally, `grep -rnI "winepath.exe" ~/.config/` also returns nothing (I had to `sudo` because access denied). _I should probably mention that while using the script, the programs don't run. Also, I attached `chmod +x` into the script, not sure where it's supposed to be. Before, it was before everything. Now, it's after `#!/bin/sh`._

Comment: Heh, that's funny, but I think I got what is this. The `winepath.exe` is an app that exist inside of wine environment *(i.e. it is like `wine notepad` — the notepad is also only there)*. And the `-u` is an option to the `winepath.exe`. This app actually have a help for command options, and it says that `-u` option converts a Windows path to unix path. You can try it yourself — e.g. `"C:\\foo"` → `/home/constantine/.wine/dosdevices/c:/foo` on my system. Perhaps pcmanfm needs to convert the paths, but I have no idea why is it, and why the path argument is missing.

Comment: I guess it's safe then. I was thinking it might be a virus in Windows that found a way to dig into Ubuntu. If `winepath.exe` is a known program, then this should be nothing to worry about. Many thanks. ^w^